# Database with pandas: adding new data

Tags: python, database, excel, pandas

I have a lot of `Excel plains` and I load them using `pandas`, process the data and as an `output it writes all data in a Excel plain` that is my "database".

The Database has to follow a pattern in the date index, e.g. `2017-01-01 (yyyy-mm-dd)`, 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03 ... 2017-12-31 ... and so on.

But the plains that are my inputs do not follow a rule with the date. My processing deals with it and do the correctly match with the input plain and output database indexes creating a new file: `pd.to_excel('database\databaseFinal.xlsx')`. My problem is `adding new values to the existing database and still process the indexes to respect the pattern.`

for example:

DATABASE.xlsx:

```
    date         Name1  Name2
    2017-01-01   23.2   18.4
    2017-01-02   21.5   27.7
    2017-01-03   0      0
    2017-01-04   0      0
```

plain input to update the database:

```
    date         Name1  
    2017-01-04   32.5
```

process data...
after merging data:

```
    date         Name1_x  Name2  Name1_y
    2017-01-01   23.2     18.4   0
    2017-01-02   21.5     27.7   0
    2017-01-03   0        0      0
    2017-01-04   0        0      32.5
```

What I want:

```
    date         Name1  Name2  
    2017-01-01   23.2   18.4  
    2017-01-02   21.5   27.7   
    2017-01-03   0      0      
    2017-01-04   32.5   0
```

In this problem I must have as `output an excel file`. I know that must be an easy and efficient way of dealing with this, but I dont want to my work was in vain

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using merge you can simple append and fill the NAN values with zero.

```
df1
         date  Name1  Name2
0  2017-01-01   23.2   18.4
1  2017-01-02   21.5   27.7
2  2017-01-03    0.0    0.0
3  2017-01-04    0.0    0.0
df2
         date  Name1
0  2017-01-04   32.5

df1.append(df2).fillna(0)
   Name1  Name2        date
0   23.2   18.4  2017-01-01
1   21.5   27.7  2017-01-02
2    0.0    0.0  2017-01-03
3    0.0    0.0  2017-01-04
0   32.5    0.0  2017-01-04
```

If you always want to keep the value from the second dataframe you can use drop_duplicate with date as subset:

```
df1.append(df2).fillna(0).drop_duplicates(subset=['date'], keep='last')
   Name1  Name2        date
0   23.2   18.4  2017-01-01
1   21.5   27.7  2017-01-02
2    0.0    0.0  2017-01-03
0   32.5    0.0  2017-01-04
```

Comment: But in this case 2017-01-04 will be duplicated. And not always my input has the date information and also there are cases that rather than getting the next index value (2017-01-04) i get 2017-01-03

Comment: What logic defines which values should be kept and which should be thrown away? Do you want to always keep the value from the second df?

Comment: Yes. I replace the 0 in the database for the non zeros from the input

Answer (score 1):

```
# Make the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-01-01', 23.2, 18.4],
['2017-01-02', 21.5, 27.7],
['2017-01-03', 0.0, 0.0],
['2017-01-04', 0.0, 0.0]]) 
df.columns = ["date","Name1","Name2"] 
df.index = df["date"] 
df = df.drop("date",axis=1)

# Change the value
df.loc["2017-01-04"]["Name1"] = 32.5
```